# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Tags: gradle

I am trying to build a gradle project. But when I run `Execute Gradle Task` with `clean` in Intellij Idea, I am getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)`

From the terminal when I run command "gradle clean build" it is running successfully.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.xml/jdk.xml.internal.SecuritySupport.getSystemProperty(SecuritySupport.java:86)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.XMLSecurityManager.getSystemProperty(XMLSecurityManager.java:530)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.XMLSecurityManager.readSystemProperties(XMLSecurityManager.java:492)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.XMLSecurityManager.<init>(XMLSecurityManager.java:206)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.<init>(XMLEntityManager.java:437)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(XML11Configuration.java:594)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:130)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.<init>(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:91)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(DOMParser.java:145)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(DOMParser.java:129)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:138)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.getDocBuilder(PomReader.java:238)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.parseToDom(PomReader.java:255)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.access$100(PomReader.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader$2.transform(PomReader.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader$2.transform(PomReader.java:138)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.LocalFileStandInExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(LocalFileStandInExternalResource.java:190)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.AbstractExternalResource.withContent(AbstractExternalResource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.local.DefaultLocallyAvailableExternalResource.withContent(DefaultLocallyAvailableExternalResource.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.doParseDescriptor(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.doParseDescriptor(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseMetaData(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromResource(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromResource(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.create(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:373)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveComponentMetaData$3(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:242)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ResolveIvyFactory$ParentModuleLookupResolver.resolve(ResolveIvyFactory.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.resolveMetaDataArtifactFile(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.getMetaDataArtifact(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.getMetaDataArtifact(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.parsePomForSelector(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.doParsePom(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.doParseDescriptor(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.doParseDescriptor(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseMetaData(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromResource(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromResource(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.create(DefaultMavenPomMetadataSource.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:126)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:444)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:373)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveComponentMetaData$3(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:242)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ResolveIvyFactory$ParentModuleLookupResolver.resolve(ResolveIvyFactory.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.resolveMetaDataArtifactFile(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.getMetaDataArtifact(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.getMetaDataArtifact(ExternalResourceResolverDescriptorParseContext.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.parsePomForSelector(GradlePomModuleDescriptorParser.java:216)

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

I am unable to understand this stacktrace. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?